# is it possible to make a mirror application in android

Tags: android

Hey is this possible to make an application which can be used to see the image of our own like we did in the mirror ie the application should be act like a hand held mirror
dont want to use the camera but want to make screen Act as mirror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is virtually impossible because the image displayed would depend on the angle of the screen.

Comment: You'd need to calculate the Plenoptic Function (http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/ASHBROOK1/node4.html) in order to do true mirroring.

Answer (score 2):

It is easily possible by placing a small periscope on the back camera

Comment: i want to make screen, glow like mirror

Comment: It will be possible around year 2500 when we invent a reflective screen with metalic colours. But until then you better carry a small periscope :)

Answer (score 1):

If the device has a front-facing camera, just turn on the camera.

Comment: nice hack +1 but I dont think he needs that

Comment: That would not work correctly, you would have to flip the image as well. Entirely possible I should think.

Comment: It depends what the O.P. means by a mirror. Just displaying the image in the camera isn't really mirroring it's just displaying the image in the camera.

Comment: Still, it is probably possible to "mirror" the image manually (swap the image on the horizontal axis), if you really want to. Seems like a waste of CPU just to duplicate a flaw that real-world mirrors have, but it should be doable.